# How to run python scripts

Tags: pycharm, python-3.8

I am a beginner in python, and now I need to start being able to execute my very basic scripts. However, I cannot get the cmd to execute my python file without closing in a second. Here are some screenshots maybe I have some wrong in my batch file.
Thank you so much for your time and help!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use python to execute python scripts.
for example, you can run the following in your command prompt

```
python testing.py
```